# What does "toggle" mean in the context of Lexplore?

Tags: netrw

The description of Lexplore says that it "toggles" a directory window on the left side, but I don't see the difference between that and Vexplore, which seems to do exactly the same thing. If I do :Lex twice in row, then a second netrw window is created, so it does not appear to turn the window off (q) as a toggle would normally mean. What does the help mean by "toggle" in this context if it does not mean to close the window? The help itself is unclear because it does not explain what the command does (any different than Vex).

Answer (score 6):

With `:Vexplore`, the current window is split in two and a netrw buffer is displayed in the new window.

Repeating that command again and again will keep splitting the current window until the left half of the workspace is filled with very narrow netrw windows.

`:Lexplore` is a *toggle*, this means that it switches between two states:

- The netrw window created with `:Lexplore` is not present.

  A new window is created.
- The netrw window created with `:Lexplore` is present.

  That window is closed.